# When button clicked, replace entire window content with an image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

**SOLVED**

So I have an issue where when I click the button, I want an image to replace the entire content of the window. But it's only replacing, what I believe to be, a part of a panel. Should I not use panels in this instance? I found some code online which didn't use panels which worked, but maybe there is a scenario where I can remove the panel and just cover the entire frame with my image when the button is clicked?

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SatNav extends JFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;

private JLabel satelliteLabel;
private JLabel aboutLabel;

private JButton satellite;
private JButton about;

public SatNav() {

    frame = new JFrame("Work Package 5");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 380);

    about = new JButton("About");
    add(about);

    event abo = new event();
    about.addActionListener(abo);

    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(about);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //This is for centering the frame to your screen.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //This for closing your application after you closing the window.
}

public class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent abo) {
        ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

        //JFrames methods
        panel.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();
        repaint();

        about.setVisible(false);
        //satellite.setVisible(false);
    }
}

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("about.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SatNav();
}
}
```

[image: The output is attached]

Comment: You're treating panel as if it has a BorderLayout, but it doesn't and instead has a default FlowLayout. Give it a BorderLayout. Better yet, use a cardLayout to swap components.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I'm going to research what that means now, as i'm still quite new. I just fixed my issue, I just added the image to the frame instead of the panel.

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to your question, you should post an answer below showing how you solved it.

Comment: Its already answered...........

Comment: "official" answer given

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're treating the panel JPanel as if it has a BorderLayout when it doesn't. Rather it has JPanel's default FlowLayout which will size components to their preferred sizes (here [0, 0]) rather than have contained components fill the container. The simple solution: give your panel a BorderLayout:

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Now when adding components, the BorderLayout constants will be respected by the container's layout.

Another and possibly better and more durable solution is to use a CardLayout to help you swap components.

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SatNav2 extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // a publicly available example image for demonstration purposes:
    public static final String SAT_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org"
            + "/wikipedia/commons/1/18/AEHF_1.jpg";
    private static final String INTRO_PANEL = "intro panel";
    private static final String IMAGE_LABEL = "image label";
    // our layout
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    // JLabel to display the image
    private JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();

    public SatNav2(Image img) {
        // put image into JLabel
        imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

        // JPanel to hold JButton
        JPanel introPanel = new JPanel();
        // add button that does the swapping
        introPanel.add(new JButton(new ShowImageAction("Show Image")));

        // set the CardLayout and add the components. Order of adding 
        // is important since the first one is displayed
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        // add components w/ String constants
        add(introPanel, INTRO_PANEL);
        add(imgLabel, IMAGE_LABEL);
    }

    private class ShowImageAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ShowImageAction(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // tell card layout to show next component
            cardLayout.next(SatNav2.this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                createAndShowGui();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() throws IOException {
        // get the image
        URL imgUrl = new URL(SAT_PATH);
        Image img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
        // pass image into our new JPanel
        SatNav2 mainPanel = new SatNav2(img);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Satellite");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```